Error: export 'ɵmarkDirty' (imported as 'ɵmarkDirty') was not found in '@angular/core'
I tried to upgrade Angular from v13 to v14, v15,v16 through nx environment, such as Npx nx migrate nx@15.2.0 I got the error message like this:
./node_modules/ngx-sub-form/fesm2020/ngx-sub-form.mjs:877:6-16 - Error: export 'ɵmarkDirty' (imported as 'ɵmarkDirty') was not found in '@angular/core'
I cannot find any solution from online. Anybody has any advice to solve this?

Without seeing package.json it is not very clear. Can you check if you have dependency ngx-sub-form? and yes try to see their npm registry page and see if they have any support for new version
